# segmentation fault for deleting a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault, language-lawyer, delete-operator

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class c1 {};
class c2 : public c1 {};
class c3 : public c1 {};
class c4 : public c2, public c3 {};

int main () {
  c4 *x1 = new c4;
  c3 *x2 = x1;
  delete x2; // segmentation fault
}
```

Hi, i am trying to understand typecasting and inheritance, i found this issue. I have a pointer to the most derived class, and typecasted (implicit) to middle any class, while deleting, i thought it should be able to delete the allocated space by the first new. In some compilers, it seem fine, but in linux gcc version 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5), it is giving segmentation fault. Not able to figure out, why? Any help/pointer/suggestion will be appreciated.

Note - Class is derived in the form of diamond problem.

Comment: You should implement virtual destructor in c3.

Comment: And it is not a diamond problem because there is no virtual inheritance. Class c4 actually has two instance of c1 in it.

Comment: thanks. i am reading more about the usage of virtual destructors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is undefined behavior. Just as you've seen, for some situations it might seem work well, for some situations it won't.

At least the base class `c3` (or `c1` and `c2`) should have a **virtual** destructor. e.g.

```
class c3 : public c1 {
public:
    virtual ~c3() {}
};
```

According to the standard, [$5.3.5/3 Delete [expr.delete]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.delete#3):

(emphasis mine)

> In the first alternative (*delete object*), if the static type of the
>   object to be deleted is different from its dynamic type, the static
>   type shall be a base class of the dynamic type of the object to be
>   deleted and **the static type shall have a virtual destructor or the
>   behavior is undefined**.

Answer (score 2):

Attempting to delete a pointer that was not returned by `new`. For solution use `virtual destructor` for the base classes. When you delete an object through a pointer to a base class, the base class needs a `virtual` destructor.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the previous answer, the `undefined` behaviour comes from the fact that casting the pointer to a base class means (most of the time, but not in your example) *slicing*: the pointer is adjusted (i.e. incremented) to point to the beginning of the embedded class.

So upon calling `delete` on the incremented pointer, you risk freeing part of memory and let some of it *dangling*.